# Same function with different variables

Tags: c#

Is there a shorter way to do it without repeating the same code so many times?

Pressing a button gives me the amount of files on each of the external devices connected to the PC, I have been leaving the programming for a long time and I return to it, I would appreciate if you told me that I have to study to avoid repeating the same code so many times.

```
private void BTNcompararunidades_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try 
    { 
        int CONSdeviceD = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadD.Text = CONSdeviceD.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadD.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceE = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadD.Text = CONSdeviceE.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadE.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceF = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadF.Text = CONSdeviceF.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadF.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceG = Directory.GetFiles(@"G:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadG.Text = CONSdeviceG.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadG.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceH = Directory.GetFiles(@"H:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadH.Text = CONSdeviceH.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadH.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceI = Directory.GetFiles(@"I:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadI.Text = CONSdeviceI.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadI.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceJ = Directory.GetFiles(@"J:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadJ.Text = CONSdeviceJ.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadJ.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceK = Directory.GetFiles(@"K:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadK.Text = CONSdeviceK.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadK.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceL = Directory.GetFiles(@"L:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadL.Text = CONSdeviceL.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadL.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceM = Directory.GetFiles(@"M:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadM.Text = CONSdeviceM.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadM.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceN = Directory.GetFiles(@"N:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadN.Text = CONSdeviceN.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadN.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceO = Directory.GetFiles(@"O:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadO.Text = CONSdeviceO.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadO.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceP = Directory.GetFiles(@"P:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadP.Text = CONSdeviceP.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadP.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceQ = Directory.GetFiles(@"Q:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadQ.Text = CONSdeviceQ.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadQ.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceR = Directory.GetFiles(@"R:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadR.Text = CONSdeviceR.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadR.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceS = Directory.GetFiles(@"S:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadS.Text = CONSdeviceS.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadS.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceT = Directory.GetFiles(@"T:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadT.Text = CONSdeviceT.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadT.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceU = Directory.GetFiles(@"U:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadU.Text = CONSdeviceU.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadU.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceV = Directory.GetFiles(@"V:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadV.Text = CONSdeviceV.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadV.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceW = Directory.GetFiles(@"W:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadW.Text = CONSdeviceW.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadW.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceX = Directory.GetFiles(@"X:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadX.Text = CONSdeviceX.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadX.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceY = Directory.GetFiles(@"Y:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadY.Text = CONSdeviceY.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadY.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceY = Directory.GetFiles(@"Y:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadY.Text = CONSdeviceY.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadY.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }

    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceZ = Directory.GetFiles(@"Z:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadZ.Text = CONSdeviceZ.ToString();
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadZ.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }
}
```

Comment: Create a method that takes the path you want to search, and the label you want to updated.

Comment: One of the `LBLUnidadD` references looks like a typo.

Comment: @juharr is right. You will call it like `YourMethod(LBLUnidadD, "D:\"); YourMethod(LBLUnidadE, "E:\");` etc.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about that mistake, I hadn't noticed it.
I think that if I investigate what you told me I will avoid this kind of mistakes.

Comment: You can also enumerate drives using [`DriveInfo.GetDrives`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives?view=netframework-4.8) instead of hard-coding the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

A helper method like this could help

```
public static void Try(string s, object ctrl ) // Change object to type of the controll you're using
{
    try
    {
        int i = Directory.GetFiles(s, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        ctrl.Text = i.ToString();
    }
    catch { ctrl.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }
}

(...)

Try(@"D:\", LBLUnidadD);
Try(@"E:\", LBLUnidadE);
Try(@"F:\", LBLUnidadF);
```

---

It's very good that you are trying to improve it as there is a bug in your code:

```
    try
    {
        int CONSdeviceE = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        LBLUnidadD.Text = CONSdeviceE.ToString();  <-----------D
    }
    catch { LBLUnidadE.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; } <-----------E
```

---

---

## With some reflection magic

I never recommend using reflection in real systems but here's a version for fun

```
Try(new { LBLUnidadD });
Try(new { LBLUnidadE });
Try(new { LBLUnidadF });
}



public static void Try<T>(T ctrl ) where T: class
{
    var p = typeof(T).GetProperties()[0];
    var o = (A)(object)p.GetValue(ctrl);// Change A to what LBLUnidadD is (Is it 'Label'?)
    try
    {
        var driveLetter = p.Name.Last();
        int i = Directory.GetFiles(driveLetter+@":\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
        o.Text = i.ToString();
    }
    catch { o.Text = "Device Dont Connected"; }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is very obvious, but if I'm using a label as a control would this look like this?         public static void Try(string s, Label ctrl)

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
In both codes this appears on the label: An object reference is required for the field, method or property.

The first code is easier for me to understand for my current level.


I post a picture in my question, I don't know how to post a picture in this comment, I'm new, I created my account here a few minutes ago
.

Comment: THANK U SO MUCH!, for ur answer. I just change: 
public static <----- void Try(string s, object ctrl TO: public void. And its work fine. Thank u again. :)